# Install localectl in Debian based docker container

Tags: docker

The command line utility `localectl` is present on Debian based systems. However, it is not present in the dockerized version of the distro

```
$ localectl
bash: loaclectl: command not found
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install docker and docker-compose on your system
2. `docker pull debian`
3. `docker run -it debian bash`
4. `localectl`

I wanted to know if there was a way to install it inside the docker container of debian or ubuntu image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll regularly find that some packages aren't a part of the base Docker images - this is because the maintainers only put in what is absolutely necessary so that they run as small as possible.

I discovered that `localectl` is a part of the [systemd](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/localectl.1.html) package - which makes sense, as systemd and initd aren't really necessary in Docker - which is meant to only run a single process. While the documentation I linked goes to Ubuntu, the following will install the binaries needed:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install -y systemd
```

Comment: You answer did provide the immediate solution, but I guess the problem goes much deeper. Since we're inside a docker container, even after installing `systemd`, `localectl` doesn't work. It says `Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory` because `systemd` isn't the PID 1 process. By any chance you can help out with that!?

Comment: @codingCoffee is right, this does not work, at least on ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04

Comment: Same here, systemd installation is not enough, getting the following error: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to create bus connection: Host is down`